# Is it possible to have a calculation within a CountIf statement in Excel?

Tags: excel, countif

Hopefully someone can help me here.

In Excel have a column of football (soccer) scorelines and venues in the format

```
Venue A 1-1
Venue B 1-0
Venue A 0-2
Venue B 0-3
```

etc.

What I want to do, without creating an additional calculated column, is to return a count of wins, ties and losses for a particular venue.

So in the above example a count of venue A where the number to the left of the hyphen is greater than the number to the right of the hyphen, would be the number of wins at venue A.
The same count where the two numbers are equal would be the number of ties at venue A and so on...

Using this:

(VALUE(LEFT(F3:F7, FIND("-", F3:F7)-1))-VALUE(RIGHT(F3:F7, FIND("-", F3:F7)-1)))

I can find the difference between the two values

What I would like to be able to do is something like...

COUNTIFS(E3:E7,"Venue A",(VALUE(LEFT(F3:F7, FIND("-", F3:F7)-1))-VALUE(RIGHT(F3:F7, FIND("-", F3:F7)-1))), "0" )

This formula says the arrays are of different sizes.

I know one solution would be just to add a new column with the above code calculating the difference and then do a simple CountIFS on the Venue and that Value but is it possible to do this without creating that column?

Comment: You need `SUMPRODUCT`. `COUNTIFS` will only work with ranges, not arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have not more than 9 goals per team, you can use array formulas as shown below:
[image]

Value of D2:
`=SUM(IF(MID($A:$A;7;1)=D$1;1;0)*IF(MID($A:$A;9;1)>MID($A:$A;11;1);1;0))`

For D3 and D4 change the sign. For ties use "=", for losses uses "<".
For E and further columns you just need to replace D1 with E1, F1, etc.

Make sure to use array formulas. To do that, instead of pressing enter press Control+Mayus+Enter. You should see the formula with curly brackets:
[image]

Comment: Just one thing on this... The venue and scoreline are separate columns (not clear from what I posted)

So Column A is the Venue A, Venue B etc with Column B being the scorelines in the format 1-1, 2-0 etc. (and there are no scorelines of 10!)

I've tried adjusting your code myself and can get the correct output for the cells i.e. 1, 0 where appropriate but can't get the product to work - as I type this I'm thinking maybe I need SUMPRODUCT now...

Comment: OK just for anyone else who comes across this I solved it by a combination of SUMPRODUCT and what Adrian had suggested

SUMPRODUCT(IF(E$3:E$10 = "Venue A", 1, 0), (IF(MID(F$3:F$10, 1, 1) > (MID(F$3:F$10, 3, 1)), 1, 0)))